# expected ‘double (*)(double)’ but argument is of type ‘double’ in C

Tags: c

I need help, am trying to calculate the integral of a function using trapezoidal  rule in C.

I am trying to use a function as a variable in another function but I am having issues compiling, it gives the same message as the title.

Here's then Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double test(double x){
    return pow(x,2);
}

double tarpez(double a,double b, int n, double (*test)(double )){
    /*x[n] represents the parameter
      y[n] respresents the parameter ,a initial x, 
      h is the length of divided spaces*/

    double h,x[n],y[n],So,Se;//So-- sum of odd, Se- ...even
    h = (b-a)/n;
    if (n%2==1){
        n+=1;
    }
    for (int i ; i<=n;i++){
        x[i]= a+i*h;
        y[i] = test(x[i]);
        printf("%lf\n",y[i] );

    }   
}

int main(void){
    double x,a,b,fn;
    int n;
    fn =
        tarpez(a,b,n,test(x));
}
```

Comment: The last argument to `tarpez` is supposed to be a function. You're calling the function instead of passing the function itself.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: `tarpez(a,b,n,test)`

Comment: "function as a variable" is also known as a function pointer.

Comment: I guess tarpez is a creative misspelling of trapez, amirite?

Comment: thats right damn typo! haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primo, double (*test)(double ) is type name like int or float. So you need declare double (*test)(double ) foo where foo is variable name (like int n).
Sceundo, name of type can't be name of function. Pointer of function need return tupe, args types and no-reserved name. So try double (*custom_name)(double ).
Tertio, in main function no tarpez(a,b,n,test(x)). Use tarpez(a,b,n,test); You use only name in this space.

PS
Try use typedef.